# Non-English Language support via SolrNet

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrnet

I am using SolrNet to search over Solr from an .NET application.
Everything works fine when I search over English words.  However if I
use spanish words like **`español`**, I get no search result though I
have indexed them. When I debugged over Solr, I found that the query
was parsed as **`espaA+ol`**.

Do I have to do some UTF-8 encoding or does SolrNet supports search over only ASCII characters?

Comment: Indexing works fine. I can index documents containing spanish characters but querying with same character set provides me with no result as it is encoded in the way explained above.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a SolrNet issue, it is related to how Solr handles characters that are not in the first 127 ASCII character set. The best recommendation is add the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) to your Solr field where you are storing the Spanish words.

As an example, if you were using the `text_general` fieldType as defined in the Solr example which is setup as follows in the schema.xml file:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I would recommend modifying it as follows adding the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory to the index and query analyzers.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Also, please note that you will need to reindex your data after making this schema change for the changes to be reflected in the index.

Comment: Is there a way to store the actual unicode chars into the index? Because while this may work for spanish, won't it fail rather horribly on chinese?

Comment: There are also language specific analysis components available at - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis In most cases you will need to test with your specific language and find the right combination of analysis to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to specifically keep those characters in the index? If you don't need to, it would be better to use something like

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
```

so 'español' would be indexed as 'espanol' and searching for any of them would find 'español' (same for á, ü etc).