# Solr stopwords with spanish accent not working in commerce

Tags: solr, utf-8, stop-words, websphere-commerce

Solr **stopwords.txt** file has few accent characters written due to which an exception of 'wrong encoding is thrown while solr server is started or index is build in **WEBSPHERE Commerce 7**. 
For E.g: é , í characters are present in my stopwords file.

The exception is:
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException : Wrong Encoding?):../../conf/sopwords.txt

I was going through your reply for this earlier at link: [Non-English Language support via SolrNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493830/non-english-language-support-via-solrnet)

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would open a PMR if there are problems or questions, they just can't do the "work".   That's why you pay for IBM Software Support.